# ASP .NET server control vs. HTML control

Tags: asp.net, html, controls, telerik-grid

At the moment, in my team, there is a conflict when deciding to use HTML control or ASP .NET server control.
For instance, in order to implement a grid view list that supports reordering, we have two options:

1. Use HTML controls (ul, ol) and jQuery sortable. By using this approach, we can use the markup and style after slicing PSD and implement it rightaaway. We can fetch data by using jQuery ajax.
2. Use ASP .NET control like Telerik Grid (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx). Using this option, we have to change style of server control to match the design.

Considering performance and secutiry, please help me figure out which option is better?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It's hard to say with out knowing all the details.  Try 'em both.  Write small proof-of-concept test pages.

Answer (score 1):

@batto 
telerik grid will wonderful you only not think for  only this time .  May be in future you need many enchantments in your project at that time you really need to use that feature's . So from my view you use Telerik controls .

Answer (score 0):

For only display purpose Jquery grid is better option, it will increase the performance.

Answer (score 0):

HTML control is a compromise between traditional ASP.NET programming and web control and it has a limited object-oriented interface. We usually use HTML control to have a smooth HTML code that will be generated and sent to the browser

If you want a powerful control, choose web control over HTML control!

It hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a server control. I would probably just use a

You have the ability to do what ever you want with them.  If you want to do sorting using jquery then it should not be too different than how you sort ul's.  If needed I can provide a sample.  You also have the power of the server.  If you tie other events such as add or remove then you will want the server control. Its a bit easier to pass data back and forth.